# Configure MSOutlook configured to Yahoo/gmail server

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I need to transfer my office mails in Outlook archived pst form to my Home computer.

While configuring MSOutlook, it needs a valid incoming and outgoing mail server details.
I have only Yahoo email and gmail. Suppose my Yahoo id is abc@yahoo.co.in
Then what entries should I give for mail server?

Once I can configure and start MSOutlook, I can import the mails from PST file.
But the problem here is how to configure Outlook with yahoo mail server?

Answer (score 0):

The regular pst file includes your profile.  I don't know for sure whether an archive pst does also.  You could just open it and see if your settings are there.  You don't need to import from a pst file, you just open it.  There are several routes.  One is File-> Open-> Outlook Data File.  It sounds like you know your way around the Outlook menu system, but in case you need it, this [link](http://www.howto-outlook.com/faq/newprofile.htm#create) covers setting up a profile and adding in archive files.

If you do need to create a Yahoo or GMail profile, [this link](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-settings.html) provides all of the settings for those and other major email services (US settings; I can't vouch for whether they are the same for you).  You can verify them on your office machine, but at the very least, these identify the fields you need to deal with.

Extracting the Yahoo and GMail information:

**Yahoo! Mail Settings**

Yahoo Mail offers standard POP3 access for receiving emails incoming through your Yahoo mailbox, by using your favorite email client software. To setup your email client for working with your Yahoo account, you need to select the POP3 protocol and use the following mail server settings:

```
Yahoo Incoming Mail Server (POP3) - pop.mail.yahoo.com (SSL enabled, port 465)

Yahoo Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) - smtp.mail.yahoo.com (SSL enabled, port 995)
```

POP **Yahoo! Mail Plus** email server settings (this is a premium service in the US but I'm aware that in some countries, this is part of their regular service, you just need to use the right servers).

```
Yahoo Plus Incoming Mail Server (POP3) - plus.pop.mail.yahoo.com (SSL enabled, port 995)

Yahoo Plus Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) - plus.smtp.mail.yahoo.com (SSL enabled, port 465, use authentication)
```

**Google GMail Settings**

The Google GMail service offers email client access for retrieving and sending emails through your Gmail account. However, for security reasons, GMail uses POP3 over an SSL connection, so make sure your email client supports encrypted SSL connections.

```
Google Gmail Incoming Mail Server (POP3) - pop.gmail.com (SSL enabled, port 995)

Outgoing Mail Server - use the SMTP mail server address provided by your local ISP or smtp.gmail.com (TLS enabled, port 587)
```

Comment: I tries to setup Outlook by 'Add New Account' which points to my already existing yahoo account, abc@yahoo.co.in. Gave the fol inputs :                                                        Yahoo Incoming Mail Server (POP3) - pop.mail.yahoo.co.in 
Yahoo Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) - smtp.mail.yahoo.co.in

Comment: Then it's already set up.  You don't need to add it.  If you want to add a different account, there's an add account option.  If you need to modify an existing account, you can.

Comment: See if this link is helpful: http://techblissonline.com/yahoo-pop-email-settings/

Comment: @kakoli - Also: https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070329234931AAsGeTc  and  https://ph.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080120031225AAywHMd

Comment: Got the answer to why it was failing.You should be a mail plus member for pop access.

Comment: @kakoli - so were you able to get this working for any account?  BTW, Yahoo policies may vary by location.  I think premium service was required here at one point for POP access and they dropped that requirement.  There are a number of free email services with POP.